# Can't read fodler /var/www in linux, using phpmyadmin in docker

Tags: linux, docker, phpmyadmin

i just install phpmyadmin in docker, running it use `docker start phpmyadmin`.
i can access `http://localhost/` and display `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page`.
when access my folder within `/var/www` then i get this message
`Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80`

Comment: Maybe a directory permission issue?

Comment: its like protected folder?

Answer (score 1):

The phpMyAdmin Docker image runs on port 8080 by default, so based on your description, what you're seeing is not the phpMyAdmin web page at all. Try accessing http://localhost:8080.

Your comment about accessing `/var/www` directly makes no sense to me because your web browser looks at the web root (which is actually `/var/www/html/` in this case), and you'll access that by using http://localhost:8080/ rather than needing any subdirectory information after it.